# Always displaying the first row of a DataGrid, even if it's empty?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

It seems it would be very simple, but I can't seem to figure out.  The way it is right now, before a query is done and data is added to the DataGrid by binding, the DataGrid is displayed only as its headers, with no rows.  I'd like the first row to always be displayed, even before a query is ran, for visual appeal, is there a way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before binding to your data, insert a blank row: `datagrid.Items.Add(0);`

Delete the blank row right before querying:  `datagrid.Items.Remove(0);`

(Edited to reflect OP feedback.)

Comment: That actually worked very well!  Didn't need binding or anything.  Just `datagrid.Items.Add(0);`  and then `datagrid.Items.Remove(0)` before query is ran. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you could enable adding a row in the DataGrid, it will create an empty row that is editable for you.